# Swift: NSUserDefaults not setting straight away

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, alamofire

## What I have

I have a view controller (**SelectNameViewController**) with a UITableView on with a list of names. When the user clicks a name, it goes to a ViewController (**ResultController**) which has a container view that loads 3 ViewControllers (**vc1**,**vc2**,**vc3**) allowing the user to scroll through.

On **ResultController** I have an alamofire request that connects to a JSON file and downloads information based on the name selected:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, sendyURLSet, parameters: ["name": passedName, "api_key": api_key])
.responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
       case .Success:

       if let value = response.result.value {
          let json = JSON(value)

          self.age = json["age"].stringValue
          self.userInfo.setValue(self.age, forKey: "age")

        }
       case .Failure(let error):
           print(error)
   }
}
```

On **VC1** I have this in my **viewDidAppear**

```
if let a = userInfo.stringForKey("age") {
        print("Age:  \(a)")
    } else {
        print("nope")
}
```

## Problem

I am having trouble loading data on a PageViewController child view after the content has been loaded from an Alamofire request.

When the user clicks a name and is taken to the **ResultController** the 3 views load into the container view. The first screen to appear is **vc1**.

However, in the console I just get:

> Nope

If I swipe to **vc2** and then back to **vc1** I get:

> Age 32

in the console.

## Question

Can someone tell me why the value is not showing up on the first presentation of the ViewController (**vc1**) and tell me how to fix it?

It is driving me crazy

Comment: Do not use `NSUserDefaults` to pass data between controllers. Use segues, protocol - delegate pattern or notifications (in order of recommendation priority)

Comment: There are no segues for the three view controllers as they are loaded into a container view.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, the callback to your `Alamofire.request` is called after `viewDidAppear`, and that explains why you do not see the value you set in the callback.

What you should want is that your code

`if let a = userInfo.stringForKey("age") {
        print("Age:  \(a)")
    } else {
        print("nope")
}`

is called after the callback is executed.

You have several means to this:

- `resultsController` calls into `VC1` to make it update its UI;
- load `resultsController` from the callback (actually, you make sure you call its `view` method for the first time in the callback, i.e., when you add it as a subview to the parent);
- or, you use `KVO` to make `VC1` observe any changes to `userInfo.age`. This approach requires customising `NSUserDefaults` by way of deriving a new class from it.

Comment: I figured it was to do with the request. How do I, from vc1 wait for the view (ReportsView) to finish it's business before loading the data?

Comment: I am a little noobie at this so I do appreciate your help :)

Comment: please, see the 3 options I mention.

Comment: ok, So with option 3 (KVO) am I right to believe that this option only works on a class of NSObject ? so that wouldn't work, right? option 2: resultsController has the alamofire code in, so would it be possible to reload the view? Would that not make a reoccurring loop? This leaves option 1 - I'm not sure how to 'call into' a view controller. Any pointers?

Comment: KVO actually works in Swift, no problems -- but admittedly is the hardest option if you have never used KVO (either in Swift or ObjC). As to option2, i understand that `resultsController` at some point instantiates `VC1` and adds it view as subview. Is that right? You should run that code from the callback. As to option 3, just keep a reference to `VC1` in a property of `resultsController`, then call `viewDidAppear` on that reference in your callback (or even better, define an ad-hoc method, e.g., `updateUI`, that would be cleaner)

Comment: BTW, if you are using interface builder, you need to define a `IBOutlet` reference in resultsController's class, then visually bing `VC1` to that outlet in interface builder -- for option 3.

Answer (score 0):

looks like vc1 is being loaded quicker than the data fetch is completing.

Either wait for the data to be loaded before you load the new controllers, or set the label directly when the data has completed

Answer (score 0):

Try following one. I think it may help you.

 On completion of your network call (in completion handler block) set values to UI elements like label,  using outlets. And call `- (void)setNeedsLayout` method.
This method to indicate that the layout of a layer’s sublayers has changed and must be updated. The system typically calls this method automatically when the layer’s bounds change.